# How to reference other doxygen comments to avoid repeating yourself

Tags: doxygen, idl

I am working on documenting an interface, which is described in an IDL. In this interface I am attempting to use doxygen to generate documentation.

I am looking for a way to "repeat" doxygen documentation in multiple places.

For example

```
struct StructA 
{
   long identifierA;   ///< Some description about this identifierA
   long identifierB;   ///< Some other description about this identifierB
   SomeTypeA dataA;
   SomeTypeB dataB;
}
struct StructB
{
   long identifierA;   // This member should be documented the same as StructA::identifierA
   long identifierB;   // This member should be documented the same as StructA::identifierB
   SomeTypeC dataC;
}
```

In this example, imagine that `identifierA` and `identifierB` in both data structures represent the same thing, for example, some way of indexing/identifying data (e.g. a key).

**Q:** If I describe the identifiers in `StructA`, how can I repeat the documentation for the identifiers in `StructB`? Obviously I could copy and paste, but that is going to create headaches if I need to change the documentation. It seems like there should be a way to reference the documentation for it in one place which may be some other place than `StructA` or `StructB`.

Or perhaps I am thinking about this documentation in the wrong way?

Comment: Did you have a look at e.g. \copydoc StructA::identifierA

Comment: @albert Ah, perfect. I missed this. I think this will work just fine. Make it an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
struct StructB
{
   long identifierA;   ///< @copydoc StructA::identifierA
   long identifierB;   ///< @copydoc StructA::identifierB
   SomeTypeC dataC;
}
```